# Prevent video being loaded on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, video, responsive

I have a video that I do not want to be loaded below 480px, as this is reducing the page speed.

HTML is:-

```
    <div class="main-vid">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%">
            <source src="/video/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

I have tried the following JQuery but the video is still being loaded:-

```
if ( $(window).width() > 480) {      

} 
else {
  $('video').hide();
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Where you have added that JQuery code ?
You need to add the same while loading the page in $(document).ready function..

$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ( $(window).width() > 480) {

    }
    else {
        $('video').hide();
    }
});

Comment: Better use CSS for such things, really.

Comment: Hi I tried CSS and using 'Harsh' advice, however this will still load the video in the background. Its a big file so will slow down the page

Comment: Thinking about this backwards. Don't set source in the html and set it when size is appropriate

Comment: charlietfl - thank you. Do you have an example of this please? Thank you

Comment: `$('#myVideo source').attr('src', '/video/home.mp4')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to set the video `src` when the width is greater than 480 and unset/clear the `src` for device with less than 480.

```
if ( $(window).width() > 480) { 
       $('#myVideo source').attr('src','video/mp4');
       $('#myVideo').get(0).load();
       $('#myVideo').get(0).play(); 
} 
else { 
    $('#myVideo source').attr('src',''); 
  }
```

Link to working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ut1faksr/2/